# How to run / install xcodebuild?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3, xcodebuild

If I try to run xcodebuild from the command line, I receive the message:

error: can't exec '/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild' (No such file or directory)

But, xcrun appears to work.

Does this mean xcodebuild is not installed? I installed the command line tools in Xcode 4.3.1
Is there something I need to do to get this to work?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

```
sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seems that xcodebuild is located within /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin. But why do I need to run this command? Why can't I directly run xcodebuild from the command line like xcrun... ? Thanks.

Comment: I think I understand why - Because Xcode 4.3.1 is an app now, and as a result all tools should be in that location.

Comment: thanks, this one bit me when I tried to install libsdl on Macports

Comment: If you have a previous rev of Xcode it was installed under /Developer.  As you point out, with 4.3.1 it is now an application located in /Applications and the stuff under /Developer is now embedded deep within.  There is a lot of legacy environment in the system as a whole, and in your user home that will point to the old location.  xcode-select fixes this.

Comment: You don't need to include the whole path to Developer, just do `sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/` and it determines the correct location.

Comment: I tried above command and then execute below command still it is giving same error /Applications/Xcode.app/Content/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project Monotouch.TTTAttributedLabel-master/TTTAttributedLabel.xcodeproj -target TTTAttributedLabel -sdk iphonesimulator -configuration Release clean build

Comment: Great answer, even 6 years later I find this to still work.